# Clear all SharedPreferences android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, logout

Iam saving my user login details into my SharedPreferences file. The problem is when I try to clear the ShredPreferences, the details dont clear. When the next user logs in his details are not shown.

Here is my code:-

Save.java

```
sessionManager.createLoginSession(username, deviceId,  name );
```

SessionManagement.java

SharedPreferences pref;

```
   // Editor for Shared preferences
        Editor editor;

        // Context
        Context _context;

        // Shared pref mode
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

        // Sharedpref file name
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";

    public SessionManagement(Context context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor = pref.edit();
        }

        public void createLoginSession(String emailId, String deviceid,String usersname)
        {
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

            editor.putBoolean(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED, true);
            editor.putString(KEY_EMAILID, emailId);

            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICEiD, deviceid);

            editor.putString(KEY_USERSNAME, usersname);


            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }

        /**
         * Get stored session data
         * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
        {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

            user.put(KEY_EMAILID, pref.getString(KEY_EMAILID, null));

            user.put(KEY_DEVICEiD, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICEiD, null));

            user.put(KEY_USERSNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERSNAME, null));


            // return user
            return user;
        }
        /**
         * Check login method wil check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin()
        {
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn())
            {
                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                  _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }

       // This function clears all session data and redirect the user to LoginActivity
        /**
             * Clear session details
             * */
            public void logoutUser()
            {
                // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
                //editor.clear();



                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEiD);
                editor.remove(KEY_EMAILID);

                editor.remove(KEY_USERSNAME);

                editor.commit();

                // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);
            }

            public boolean isLoggedIn()
            {
                return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
            }
```

Logout.java

```
SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());
        session.logoutUser();
```

finish();

Comment: instead of remove put NULL value for all preferences

Comment: editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEiD).commit();
 editor.remove(KEY_EMAILID).commit();
 editor.remove(KEY_USERSNAME).commit();

Comment: A bit out of this scope, as I belive the last answer solved your problems
I would be careful with what you store in SharedPrefs, as any device with root access can navigate there and open the prefs as ordinary xml file and see your user credentials
I'd suggest encrypting the data you store there, if its something so private

Comment: editor.clear().commit();

Comment: SoftwareSainath I tried your approach but still the same result

Comment: I am wondering if application context is doing something weird. Do this. Just for the heck of it, wherever you are calling, createLoginSession, after calling it, call the logoutUser immediately with the same context. Another thing you can try is before logging out, read one of the current value and display using Toast. Just some debugging suggestions to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this **structure**

```
public void logoutUser() {
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    editor.putString(KEY_TOKEN, "");
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, "");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: I also use shared prreferences in my app in order to use it for an account of on board account management. So I used the three classes like described here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/70125/first-steps-in-android-accounts-with-sharedpreferences-ui-changes-why?noredirect=1#comment93717_70125

Can anybody give me a hint, why I cannot change the once created account ?

Comment: **Page Not Found** and can you me more details please :D

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi Still the same problem

Comment: The Scenario is :
1- you must put the username and password on the **mSharedPreferences** when the user logging on.


  2-you must clear the **mSharedPreferences** when the user logout , but REMOVE the **mSharedPreferences** values.

Comment: My page cannot be found? I can navigate to it. You not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
         * Clear session details
         * */
        public void logoutUser(){

            // Clearing all user data from Shared Preferences
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();


            // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

Try the above code.Hope it will work.
```